# Is Scikit Learn's Support Vector Classifier hard margin or soft margin

Tags: scikit-learn, svm

I was wondering if the support vector classifier below from scikit learn is hard margin or soft margin?

```py
from sklearn import svm
clf = svm.SVC()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Though very late, I don't agree with the answer that was provided for the following reasons:

- *Hard margin classification* works only if the data is linearly separable (and be aware that the default option for `SVC()` is that of a `'rbf'` kernel and not of a linear kernel);
- The primal optimization problem for an *hard margin classifier* has this form:[image]
- On the other hand, as you might see from the [guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#svc), the considered primal optimization problem in scikit-learn is the following:
  [image]

This formulation - which in literature identifies the optimization problem for a *soft margin classifier* - makes it work also for non-linearly separable datasets and introduces:

- `zeta_i`, which measures how much instance i is allowed to violate the margin (the functional margin can be less than 1 in passing from the first to the second formulation);
- hyperparameter `C`, which is a portion of the "penalty" imposed to the  objective function for permitting instances to have functional margin less than 1.

Eventually, as you might see in sklearn [doc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC), hyperparameter `C` must be strictly positive, which enforces the idea that `SVC()` does provide soft margin classification. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69836915/sklearn-built-in-function-for-hard-margin-svm) is another SO reference.