# Sklearn built-in function for Hard margin SVM

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

I know that there is a built-in function for soft margin SVM as follows.

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
clf = SVC(C=1, kernel = 'linear')
clf.fit(X, y)
```

But for Hard margin SVM, we need `C=0`, right? But the code report error `ValueError: C <= 0` when I let `C=0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no hard-margin SVM in scikit-learn, as it is not very useful model. Numercically you can get very close to it by just setting `C=1e10`, but it might lead to convergence issues, as in dual formualtion of SVM C is an upper bound on the lagrange multipliers.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that there is no hard-margin SVM in scikit-learn. However, I don't think that C=1e-10 is the correct numerical way to create hard SVM. We should set up large C to get hard SVM, since larger C leads to less misclassified cases and Hard SVM doesn't allow any misclassified cases.